# Clear a DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2S variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

How do we clear out a `DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2S` variable so that it can be reused? The declaration goes as below:

```
DECLARE
   l_updt_stmnt            DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2S;

BEGIN
   Open LOOP
    l_updt_stmnt(1) := 'some dynamic sql statements';
    <parse the above statement>
   Close LOOP;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  <Print statement>
END;
```

I just want to reuse the `l_updt_stmnt` to generate dynamic sql statements multiple times.

Can anyone help.?

Comment: You can just assign a new value, or null. What problem are you having with this? And why are you using a collection if you're only using one element?

Comment: That was just an example that i was giving. the procedure doesn't use one element. It has many. Assigning NULL does not work. And .DELETE method works as mentioned below. Thanks for your response @Alexpoole.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2S is defined as PL/SQL Associated Array (Collection):

```
type varchar2s is table of varchar2(256) index by binary_integer;
```

to clear out all values you need to call `DELETE` method:

```
begin
...
   l_updt_stmnt.DELETE; -- cleanup array
...
end;
/
```